# How to convert system date to YYYYMM format by using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert sysdate in YYYYMM format to validate the expiry date, this is the query I have written but am facing the below error.

```sql
select to_char (to_date(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYYMM') from dual;
```

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff has shown you how to do exactly what you asked for, but I suspect there is a larger issue in "to validate expiry date"  I think your 'how to convert' question is really an x-y question.  (see https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to convert `sysdate` to a date.  So just use:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna to format the date, try "DATE_FORMAT" way:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-11-11 13:14:01','%m%Y')
```

or you wanna to get the difference between the expired date and sysdate,you may try "DATEDIFF":

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2001-01-01','2001-02-02')  -> -32
```